# Aplicación java no ejecuta a pesar de tener instalado JDK

Tags: java, maven, aplicación-escritorio, maven-compiler-plugin, launch4j

acabo de crear una app de escritorio con java swing y maven pero cuando intento ejecutar el .exe que cree a partir del .jar me sale el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe poniendo varias versiones de jre desde la 1.5 pero tampoco funciono. Algunos jars si me ejecutan y otras me sale este mensaje y siempre me pide el jre que ya tengo o una version anterior.

Comment: Prueba hace una copia de la carpeta `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_322` cámbiale el nombre de la carpeta a `jre` y pégala en el mismo directorio que el `.exe` de tu aplicación, después ejecútala y eso debería de solucionar el error.

Comment: En la.imagen se observa que esta definida  la versión. 1.8 como mínimo.Instala la versión 1.8 o baja la versión.